# log4j unique id in front of all logged messages?

Tags: logging, log4j

How can I add a unique ID to `log4j` output for all levels (to track which requests belong together on multithread machines)?

`log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern = ???`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a multi threaded machines, you should make use of the threadID/thread-Name to track the logs.

From the log4j doc,

```
For example, the PatternLayout with the conversion pattern "%r [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" 
will output something akin to:

176 [main] INFO  org.foo.Bar - Located nearest gas station.
```

Read [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_patternlayout.htm) if you need more idea on Conversion patterns.